# Android RunningAppProcessInfo Service state

Tags: android

How can I put an Android app into Service state (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo. IMPORTANCE_SERVICE )?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you can put an app in that state on demand. However you would reach that state if there is

- No `Activity` displayed.
- there is a [Service that has been started with the startService()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) but [*not* with `startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle)
- You're not in some special cases that are considered foreground like during the short time a `BroadcastReceiver` is executing.

---

Edit: it seems that `RunningAppProcessInfo#importance` will be "background" if there is just a started service. There is a hint for something you could try however:

documentation of `RunningAppProcessInfo.REASON_SERVICE_IN_USE` says:

> Constant for importanceReasonCode: one of the application's content providers is being used by another process. The pid of the client process is in importanceReasonPid and the target provider in this process is in importanceReasonComponent.

I guess thats is a copy/paste error (see `REASON_PROVIDER_IN_USE`) in the description and it should say: *"application's services is being used by another process"*, but regardless of that: maybe it requires that your `Service` is not just in started state but somehow used by another process. E.g. started from the outside or bound from elsewhere.

Or maybe the whole `RunningAppProcessInfo` representation is bugged and the actual code that manages the process state does it correctly.

Comment: Cand I get an example?

Comment: take any app with a service, start it and `finish` your activity. Done: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: It doesn't work, the same problem is specified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587507/android-process-importance-with-a-started-service-isnt-importance-service# , but no solution is provided

Comment: Also I don't understand why I got -1 on this question seems to me a valid question.

Comment: @CosminMihai I don't know why you got the -1, your question is pretty short though. A good question needs to look good. Also edited answer. In short: I have no idea how to get to `IMPORTANCE_SERVICE`.